# git: "Warning: Changing a readonly file"

Tags: git, commit, readonly

When I go to commit changes to a branch using,

```
git commit -a
```

`vim` is opened and I go to insert my commit message. I get this warning in the terminal:

```
W10: Warning: Changing a readonly file
```

In order to continue with the commit, I have to force write using `:x!` in `vim`, but otherwise, no problems are encountered.

At the least, this is seems to be just an annoyance. Does anyone know what's going on and/or how to fix this?

I am using Cygwin on Windows 7.

Comment: Perhaps `vim` is being invoked in read-only mode.  What are `git config --get --global core.editor` and/or `$EDITOR` set to?

Comment: Alternatively, is the commit message a readonly file? What is your umask?

Comment: My umask is `0022`, so does that mean if I didn't create the commit message file, I can't write to it?

Comment: No, `0022` is sensible.  Does `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` exist and what are its attributes?

Comment: It does exist, and its permissions are: `-r-xr-xr-x+`... Very strange to have no write permissions, I'm guessing. What should this be set to?

Comment: `0644` (`-rw-r--r--`) is appropriate for text files.  You could try just deleting it.

Comment: Seems to work. Post it as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the file `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` exists and is read-only, the simplest thing to do is to delete it - git will recreate it as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the file didn't fix it for me. Manually setting the core.editor configuration did. After running this command the problem went away for me.

git config --global core.editor "vim"

I do not know why, but this is what finally resolved the issue.  $EDITOR was set to "vim" previously and core.editor was undefined before this fix.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem....but there was a vi instance running still with that file open. No where on the screen i found that instance...so i killed it.

Answer (score 0):

There is another case which will cause COMMIT_EDITMSG file read-only. That circumstance is when you add too many files and commit them, git will make COMMIT_EDITMSG read-only to prevent you save commit message directly. It means that you should confirm you are doing the correct things and then force write it. If you are using vim or neovim as your git core eidtor, you should use command "!w" to save commit message.